# Reduce the number of SqlCommands required to send information to three tables

Tags: c#, sql, query-optimization, azure-sql-database, sqlcommand

I have the following code:

```
command = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserId from Users WHERE Username = N'" + userName + " AND " + userPassword + "= N'" + userPassword + "AND AccountStatus = 0");
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            command.Connection = conn;
            int uid = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
            if(uid > 0)
            {            
                command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE IsOnline =" + true + " WHERE UserId = 'N" + uid);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO LogonHistory OUTPUT LogonHistoryId VALUES(NULL," + uid + "," + DateTime.Now + ")");
                int id = (int) command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UsersLogOnHistory VALUES(NULL," + uid + "," + id + ")");
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                IsAuthorised = true;
                SendMessage(ID, ServerCommands.Success, IsAuthorised.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                // User does not exist 
                SendMessage(ID, ServerCommands.Failed, IsAuthorised.ToString());
            }
```

The first SQLCommand executed checks to see if the `Username` and `password` are correct and if their `account is not suspended`. It then (should) return the `Row ID.`

If the `RowID > 0` then we have a valid logon.

Next SQLCommand updates the `IsOnline` status within the same table
The next SQLCommand Inserts into the LogonHistory the Users ID, and the DateTime. Now setting `id` with the `Row Id`
finally the SQLCommand is executed to insert the `RowId` we got from the last command and the `User's Id` into `UserLogOnHistory`. (which allows us to do a quick look up) - theoretically for updating the LogonHistory for when this user logs off.

I now realise that this is a mess!

So to the Questions:

1. How do I get the RowId of the table affected by the last command.
2. How can I optimise the queries to reduce the number of SQLCommands executed - or does this seem reasonable.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: I know about SQL Injection - but as this is a private API, and not accessible to the public just another internal app it's not necessary. There is no one able to inject. But I should still use params as it is good practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can issue multiple TSQL commands in one batch by simply... *including multiple TSQL commands*. To be *thorough*, you should delimit them with `;`, but in *most* (not all) cases, that is optional and it will work without.

To get the most recently inserted identity value; `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. This only works for `INSERT`, and only with there is an `IDENTITY` column. In all other cases: `OUTPUT`.

Note; you should parameterize, but consider:

```
UPDATE IsOnline = 1 WHERE UserId = @uid;
DECLARE @lhid int
INSERT INTO LogonHistory  (explict columns here)
VALUES(NULL,@uid, GETUTCDATE());
SET @lhid = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
INSERT INTO UsersLogOnHistory (explicit columns here)
VALUES(NULL,@uid, @lhid);
```

Note that you could also do the last bits with an `INSERT` trigger on `LogonHistory`, or via `OUTPUT`.

The number of round trips here: 1

Comment: @DaveGordon the TSQL shown goes in the `SqlCommand`; then just `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", uid);` etc

Answer (score 0):

If it was me i would put all that logic in a stored procedure, it's more easy to test and makes for better decoupling.

```
CREATE PROC logon 
      @username         NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @password         NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @IsAuthorized     BIT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @UID = UserId 
    FROM Users 
    WHERE Username              = @username
        AND userPasswordHash    = CHECKSUM(@password);

    UPDATE Users
    SET IsOnline = 1
    WHERE UserId = @UID;

    INSERT INTO LogonHistory 
    VALUES(NULL,@UID,GETDATE());

    INSERT INTO UsersLogOnHistory 
    VALUES(NULL,@UID,SCOPE_IDENTITY());

    IF @UID IS NOT NULL
        SET @IsAuthorized = 1;
    ELSE 
        SET @IsAuthorized = 0;
END;
```

PS: please be considered for you colleagues privacy and hash their passwords.